# Connection timeout in playframework 1.4

Tags: playframework, playframework-1.x, unirest

I always have connection timeout when making GET request from one Controller to another with Unirest library

Application runs at

```
http://localhost:9000
```

My code in `Slash extends Controller` is:

```
 String URL = "http://localhost:9000/api/link/HZbeTR";
 Logger.info("Requesting API. URL: %s. ObjectRef: %s", URL, objectRef);
 HttpResponse<String> apiResponse = Unirest.get(URL).asString();
```

At logs I have:

```
 17:40:24,296 INFO  ~ Requesting API. URL: http://192.168.2.36:9000/api/link/HZbeTR. ObjectRef: 5g2NqY
 17:41:24,527 ERROR ~ Exception while searching for link by ident. Ident: HZbeTR, ObjectRef: 5g2NqY
 17:41:24,528 ERROR ~ ObjectRef: 5g2NqY
 com.mashape.unirest.http.exceptions.UnirestException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper.request(HttpClientHelper.java:143)
    at com.mashape.unirest.request.BaseRequest.asString(BaseRequest.java:56)
    at controllers.Slash.index(Slash.java:39)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:524)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:475)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:451)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:446)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:160)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
com.mashape.unirest.http.HttpClientHelper.request(HttpClientHelper.java:138)
    ... 8 more
17:41:24,932 DEBUG ~ Try to write on a closed channel[keepAlive:true]: Remote host may have closed the connection
```

Path `/api/link/{str}` is routed to another class extending controller.

When requesting directly to `http://localhost:9000/api/link/HZbeTR`, just few milliseconds and I have response.

I debugged networking and found that is no request like `GET http://localhost:9000/api/link/HZbeTR`

Also I put `String URL = "http://yandex.ru"` and Unirest did request to Yandex successfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In dev mode, the execution pool size is 1 so you're essentially blocking yourself. If you increase the pool size, you should fix this problem.  See the docs at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.4.x/configuration#play.pool for more info.

```
play.pool=2
```

**NB** You may need to explicitly define the mode this setting applies to.